# Laravel blade section linebreak

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel blade to do something like this:

master.blade.php

```
<script>
     var url = '@yield('url')';
</script>
```

sub.blade.php

```
@extends('master')
@section('url')
{{route('routename')}}
@stop
```

The above method works pretty well on Laravel 4.2.6 and below. However, recent update of Laravel 4.2.7 break the thing.

The output on Laravel 4.2.7:

```
var url = 'http://localhost/path
';
```

It push the end to the next line which bring error to javascript. How can I prevent pushing to next line at the end of the code when using `@yield`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try  it like this?

```
var url = @yield('url')

@section('url')
'{{ route('routename') }}';
@stop
```

Or

```
@section('url')
var url = '{{ route('routename') }}';
@stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not using newlines in the first place:

```
@extends('master')
@section('url'){{route('routename')}}@stop
```